# Ubuntu 20.04 LVM cant install bootloader install errors out

Tags: partitioning, grub2, system-installation, lvm

I have 2x2tb HDD formatted as ext4.
Booted from an install USB drive (which passed tge SHASum256 test)
selected the Install Ubuntu option
selected the keyboard, the LVM option, my user name and password and the installer started to do it's thing until ...
"sorry encountered an error unable to install bootloader on sda"
and then I was prompted to report apt-get fails, installer fails and some other auto-report errors.

Tried a few times actually.

But the same initial 'unable to install bootloader' error kept popping up.

I'd like a bit of instruction on how to run the installer, create a 4tb LVM and then, after a short period, enjoy Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: So, at attempt Number 6 the error is now an installer crash with the bug reporter uploading the crash log and I'm still without a PC

Comment: So there's no reason that the installer crashes, fails to complete or errors out ?